# Other ways to say 'each other'

Tags: synonyms

Are there any other ways to say *each other*? For example, in this sentence:

> There are times when we both need each other.

Comment: _Each_ and _other_ are separable. _There are times when each (one) of us needs the other (one)._

Comment: I'd say "both" is superfluous in your example, assuming you have previously established who the two of you are.  If not, then "both" is hopelessly vague. Either way, ditch it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are times when we both need *one another*.